# How to create PrimeFaces Mobile web site .and configuration for PrimeFaces mobile?

Tags: primefaces

How To develop primefaces  web Application which support mobile and desktop . what maven  dependency is required .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before PrimeFaces 5, mobile was a separate download that needed to be included in your project.  Now it is easier than ever to get going with PrimeFaces Mobile, as it is packaged as part of PrimeFaces 5.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
  <id>prime-repo</id>
  <name>Prime Repo</name>
  <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
</repository>
```

Add this dependency and repository . and in .xhtml you just need few tags to add .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">
<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />
<h:head>
</h:head>
  <h:body>
    <pm:page>
      <pm:header title="Title"></pm:header>

        <pm:content>
            //...
        </pm:content>

      <pm:footer title="Footer"></pm:footer>
    </pm:page>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

in pm:content put your component from primeface mobile showcase .and everything else is same .